# I need to add boarder to the strip in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am going to provide my code below. there is my plot and at the sample plot i need to recreate. I don't know how to add exactly same grey thick borders.

*Current plot*
[image]

*Desired*
[image]

```
ggplot(data = melted_df, aes(sample = value, color = Distribution)) +
  stat_qq() +
  geom_qq_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Distribution, scales = "free") + xlab('Theoretical Quantiles') + 
  ylab('Sample Quantiles') + 
  ggtitle('QQ Plot for Different Distributions against Qnorm!') + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(size = 11),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), legend.background=element_rect(fill = "lightgray"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "lightgray"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "gray45", fill = NA, size=3),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "gray45",fill = NA, size = 2), 
        strip.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `strip.background`. As the [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) state:

> `strip.background` background of facet labels (`element_rect()`; inherits from `rect`).

In your case to match your other borders you can set it to `element_rect(color = "gray45",fill = "grey90", size = 2)`

Here's an example with the `iris` dataset:

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(sample = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
     stat_qq() +
  geom_qq_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~Species, scales = "free") + xlab('Theoretical Quantiles') + 
  ylab('Sample Quantiles') + 
  ggtitle('QQ Plot for Different Distributions against Qnorm!') + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(size = 11),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), legend.background=element_rect(fill = "lightgray"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "lightgray"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "gray45", fill = NA, size=3),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "gray45",fill = NA, size = 2), 
        strip.text = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.position  = "bottom", # I prefer the legend at the bottom
        strip.background = element_rect(color = "gray45",fill = "grey90", size = 2)
        # ^^ the line above is the only thing you need to add
    )
```

[image]

Comment: thank u! may i also ask how to make strip wider than panel as in the sample?